# Reinstalling Oracle 19c on Windows 10. Fatal Error in Oracle Database Configuration Assistant

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-19c

I have tried many times to reinstall Oracle 19c. Every time, when I run setup.exe I get an error on the installation step that says [INS-20802] Oracle Database Configuration Assistant Failed. In error, there is said
[FATAL] Error while executing "C:\Users\Farrukh\Downloads\oracle\ORACLE_HOME\rdbms\admin\dbmssml.sql". Refer to "C:\Users\Farrukh\Downloads\oracle\cfgtoollogs\dbca\oracle\dbmssml0.log" for more details. Error in Process: C:\Users\Farrukh\Downloads\oracle\ORACLE_HOME\perl\bin\perl.exe
Look at the log file "C:\Users\Farrukh\Downloads\oracle\cfgtoollogs\dbca\oracle\oracle.log" for further details.
Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed.

When I go to "C:\Users\Farrukh\Downloads\oracle\ORACLE_HOME\rdbms\admin\dbmssml.sql", there is written CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY dbms_sumadv_lib AS 'C:\Users\Farrukh\Downloads\oracle\ORACLE_HOME\bin\oraqsmashr.dll';
/.

When I go to "C:\Users\Farrukh\Downloads\oracle\cfgtoollogs\dbca\oracle\dbmssml0.log", it's blank.

I deleted Oracle manually several times. Maybe I did something wrong.
Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: What, _exactly_, did you do to delete it manually?  Since this is on Windblows, a "manual deletion" would include deleting at least two directories, as well as some registry keys.  BTW, I never run DBCA as part of database _installation_.  Over the years and versions there have been several problems associated with that.  I always ran just the installation, then come back and run DBCA by itself.

Comment: I followed all these steps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHFbk_6ThAQ. I have tried this method too but couldn't run DBCA by itself.

Comment: I always utilize the actual documentation, instead of relying on some youtube clip from some unknown entity.